# Java - Enum with array field

Tags: java, arrays, refactoring, enums, constants

I want to store a list names and individual nicknames for each name as an Enum in Java. The number of nicknames will not vary. The purpose is to be able to get a full name from a nickname. Currently I have implemented this like so:

```
public enum Names {

    ELIZABETH(new String[] {"Liz","Bet"}),    
    ...
    ;

    private String[] nicknames;

    private Names(String[] nicknames)
    {
        this.nicknames = nicknames
    }


    public Names getNameFromNickname(String nickname) {
       //Obvious how this works
    }
}
```

I quite dislike having to repeat `new String[] {...}`, so I wondered if anyone could suggest an alternative, more concise, method of implementing this?

Cheers,

Pete

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Vararg parameters:

```
private Names(String... nicknames) {
```

Now you can invoke constructor without explicitly creating array:

```
ELIZABETH("Liz", "Bet", "another name")
```

[Details](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html) (see "Arbitrary Number of Arguments" section)